# Can entropy of universe remain constant in a process where P and T is constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

We know $$\Delta S(\text{univ})=\Delta S(\text{sys})+\Delta S(\text{surr})$$ at constant $P$, $T$.

$$\Delta S(\text{sys})=\Delta H(\text{sys})/T$$
$$\Delta S(\text{surr})=\Delta H(\text{surr})/T$$

As $\Delta H(\text{univ})=0$, $\Delta S(\text{sys})+\Delta S(\text{surr})=0$
Or $\Delta S(\text{univ})=0$

But we have $\Delta S(\text{univ})>0$ is a must for spontaneous process. That would mean no process is spontaneous at constant $P$, $T$.

What is the fallacy here?

Comment: What are the temperature and pressure of universe to keep them constant?

Comment: @poutnik i don't get what you mean. I have taken P, T for system only, not for universe

Comment: It is not about constant pressure or temperature but on reversibility. What ever may be the process the change in entropy for universe is positive. But zero for reversible process. This is popularly called second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @Infinite can you elaborate where reversibility comes into play here ? And what is wrong with my proof ?

Comment: The formula that you used ( ΔS = ΔH/T ) is applicable for reversible process but not for irreversible process. And in reality no process is reversible.

Comment: @Infinite ok, i missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An irreversible process at constant temperature and pressure means that the temperature of the surroundings (assumed ideal) is held at the same temperature T as the initial temperature of the system throughout the process.  So, for the surroundings, $$\Delta S_{surr}=\frac{-\Delta H_{syst}}{T}$$.  For the system, according to the Clausius inequality, $$\Delta S_{syst}=\frac{\Delta H_{syst}}{T}+\sigma$$where $\sigma$ is the amount of generated entropy due to irreversibility (always > 0).  If we add these two equations together, we obtain:  $$\Delta S_{universe}=\Delta S_{syst}+\Delta S_{surr}=\sigma>0$$If the process is carried out reversibly, then $\sigma=0$.